# Reading DLL file contents as the form of "@<DLLPath>,<Index Number>"

Tags: windows, dll

I'm trying to edit a rightclick menu in a Windows 10. Then I found Visual Studio's menu is not same as others.

If installed, The git_shell in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\git_shell`'s shown name is static string, like "Git Ba&sh Here"

But when it comes to Visual studio's AnyCode 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\AnyCode', its shown name indicates a dll file. which is `@C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\2052\VSLauncherUI.dll,-1002`

I wrote a C# program, tried to read any dll content. After browseing the internet I can't reproduce the same method as the reg or, windows simpily using "@," to approach that data.

Even worse, I even can't list that data using IO method.
The following code is made by AIGC tools.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ResourceLister
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string dllPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\2052\VSLauncherUI.dll";
                if (File.Exists(dllPath))
                {
                    string[] resourceNames = GetResourceNamesFromDll(dllPath);
                    foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ResourceName: {0}", resourceName);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not exist");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("E: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        static string[] GetResourceNamesFromDll(string dllPath)
        {
            using (var dllStream = new FileStream(dllPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var dllReader = new BinaryReader(dllStream))
                {
                    dllStream.Position = 0x3C;
                    int peHeaderOffset = dllReader.ReadInt32();
                    dllStream.Position = peHeaderOffset + 0x78;
                    int resourceTableOffset = peHeaderOffset + 0x88;
                    dllStream.Position = resourceTableOffset;
                    int numberOfResources = dllReader.ReadInt16();

                    string[] resourceNames = new string[numberOfResources];
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResources; i++)
                    {
                        dllStream.Position = resourceTableOffset + 2 + (i * 8) + 4;
                        int nameOffset = dllReader.ReadInt32();
                        dllStream.Position = resourceTableOffset + nameOffset;
                        int nameLength = dllReader.ReadByte();
                        byte[] nameBytes = dllReader.ReadBytes(nameLength * 2); 
                        resourceNames[i] = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(nameBytes);
                    }

                    return resourceNames;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got `E: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.` at last.

So, How to make it? I trend to do it in similar IO way. Any Idea helps. Thanks.

Comment: The Final Purpose is to reproduce the method of read a dll content using the title method. I wrote not very well. Apologizes and thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadstringw

Comment: @HansPassant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shloadindirectstring is the function for resolving these `@` strings.